# using ng2-toastr {ToastsManager} in Angular6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, toastr

Failed to compile.

> ./node_modules/ng2-toastr/src/toast-manager.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Subject' in
>   '/Users/siva/Desktop/Angular/chatApp/node_modules/ng2-toastr/src'

I am using ng2-toastr in angular 6 version. when I run the app the page says above error.and I imported declared all things properly

This is the code

```
import { Component, OnInit , ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './../../app.service';
import { Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  public firstName: any;
  public lastName: any;
  public mobile: any;
  public email: any;
  public password: any;
  public apiKey: any;



  constructor(
    public appService: AppService,
    public router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastsManager,
    vcr: ViewContainerRef
  ) { }
```

Comment: Please share your actual code

Comment: I am having a similar issue with ng2-toastr. It seems that Angular 6 related changes are not reflected in ng2-toastr. Still trying to figure out work around for this

Answer (score 4):

You have to replace ng2-toastr by ngx-toastr

Steps are presented here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfSvMzUK8BI

You can skip the beginning and start from 7 min

Answer (score 1):

Steps (assuming you are using Angular 6):

1. Change `ng2-toastr` to `ngx-toastr` and set the version to `8.10.2`.
2. Run `npm install` to download the package
3. Assuming you were importing `ng2-toastr.min.css` somewhere in your app.scss or angular.json, import this instead: `@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css';`
4. Replace `ToastsManager` with `ToastrService`, imported from `ngx-toastr`:

`import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';`

5. Replace `ToastModule` with `ToastrModule` (most likely you are importing this in your `app.module.ts` file:

`import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';`

6. If you were calling `toastr.setRootViewContainerRef` anywhere in your code, that can be deleted since it's no longer needed.

Hopefully that should take care of it, assuming you were not using `ng2-toastr` in a complex way.

If you still face trouble, see the video in [Mayeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014001/6854489). Additional details are also available on this page if you run into other trouble: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr/v/8.10.2

---

Source: The video linked in [Mayeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014001/6854489).