# Module has no exported member AnimationTransitionEvent

Tags: angular7

ERROR in node_modules/ng2-toastr/src/toast-container.component.d.ts(1,48): error TS2305: Module '"D:/angular basic/my-dream-app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'AnimationTransitionEvent'.

Comment: Got the same issue, seems like the contributor to the package has stopped maintaining it and with the latest Angular upgrade the core packages have shifted around and this ng2-toastr still references the old angular core packages, so would probably have to move to a different toastr package

Answer (score 1):

AnimationTransitionEvent has been renamed to AnimationEvent. Please import it from @angular/animations.

Answer (score 0):

[using ng2-toastr {ToastsManager} in Angular6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659821/using-ng2-toastr-toastsmanager-in-angular6)

Follow this URL it will get resolved.

It has proper steps as below:

1. Change ng2-toastr to ngx-toastr and set the version to 8.10.2.
2. Run npm install to download the package
3. Assuming you were importing ng2-toastr.min.css somewhere in your app.scss or angular.json, import this instead: @import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css';
4. Replace ToastsManager with ToastrService, imported from ngx-toastr:
5. import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
6. Replace ToastModule with ToastrModule (most likely you are importing this in your app.module.ts file:
   import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
7. If you were calling toastr.setRootViewContainerRef anywhere in your code, that can be deleted since it's no longer needed.